# rails with devise, How to separate login view of front and back

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm try to separate login view between front and back, I'm create devise user model and admin model inherit user.

**../model/user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable
end
```

**../model/admin.rb**

```
class Admin < User
end
```

and I duplicate every view folder in users to admin folder(sessions, users, etc..).

It's work to login page front and back, But **before_action :autenticate_(admin or user)** are separate front and back.
I can't be used together data after login in front and backend.

**So the question is:** How to used user data after login between front and backend?

Sorry my english is not good.

*Edit:*

**route**

```
... 
 # Devise
  devise_for :admin, controllers:{ :sessions => 'admin/sessions'},
    path_names: { sign_up: 'register', sign_in: 'login', sign_out: 'logout'  }
  devise_for :user, path: 'a',
    path_names: { sign_up: 'register', sign_in: 'login', sign_out: 'logout'  }
...
```

**../controllers/application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :username
  end
end
```

**../controllers/admin/application_controller.rb**

```
class Admin::ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  layout = "admin/application"

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :username
  end
end
```

[image]

I'm login in frontend success, But I can't access to backend.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't understand what you mean. Try including some example in your answer, like when you can't use the data, show a bit of code.

Comment: Sorry, I update code in controller and directory. I expect login to frontend and can access to backend with devise.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to go through devise documentation to have a better understanding of the gem.
For basics:-

1. `gem 'devise'`
2. Run `rails g devise:install`,This will generate required initializer in config file with default configurations and other important files needed
3. `rails g devise MODEL`,where MODEL is usually USER,This will create a User.rb and associate it with devise
4. `rails g devise:views`,will generate views for login,registrations,lock/unlocking views relevant to controllers

More information about using devise is  [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#getting-started)

You can find guides here on [How Tos](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-Tos)